# PHP: implode('\n', $appArray) generates extra '\'

Tags: php

I have the following array

```
$appArray=array('a', 'b', 'c');
```

I want to produce output such as `'a\nb\nc\n'`. The trouble is that when I use

```
implode('\n', $appArray)
```

I get `'a\\nb\\nc\\n'` ( note the extra backslash).

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Are you sure you're not intending: `implode("\n", $appArray)`? Newline characters aren't actually treated as newline characters when encapsulated in 'single quotes'.

Comment: I will be crazy, I used single quote which it wasn't work until saw your post.

Answer (score 9):

Use PHP_EOL (end of line) :

```
implode(PHP_EOL, $array);
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, in single quotes \n means \n (literally), not carriage return. Try using double quotes in implode ().

Answer (score 3):

Try enclosing the `\n` in double quotes.

It sounds like they're being interpreted as two characters: a backslash and an 'n', and the backslash is escaped with another backslash.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
  $selected = implode(",\n", preg_replace('/^(.*?)$/', "'$1'", $filters['selected_model']));


SELECT DISTINCT(D.model_id) AS MODEL_ID, COUNT(*) AS viewCount, t.title FROM download_logs AS D LEFT JOIN templates AS t ON D.model_id = t.id 
        WHERE D.model_type IN ('.$selected.') GROUP BY D.model_id
```